# When i use data-rel="chosen" json ajax data not binding with Dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, drop-down-menu

My Ajax function

```
$.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        dataType:'json',
        url: 'getSites',
        data: JSON.stringify(),
        success: function(json)
        {//alert("success")
             $.each(json,function(i,obj)
                        {
                        // alert(obj.value+":"+obj.text);
                        var div_data="<option value="+obj[0]+">"+obj[1]+"</option>";
                        //alert(div_data);
                        $(div_data).appendTo('#work_site'); 
                        });

        }


    });
```

and my dropdown list

```
<select  name="priority" required="required" data-rel="chosen"  id="work_site">
                                    <option value="">--Select--</option>

                                  </select>
```

If i remove "data-rel="chosen" from select option it should work perfectly. I really want to display a searchable dropdown list. What should i do?

http://jsfiddle.net/sCyYn/2/ this is i really want with dynamic content from my ajax function.

Answer (score 0):

The options are being added to the `<select>` element *after* the chosen object is instantiated. The chosen object has no idea that new options were added, so you have to tell it. You can do that by using [`.trigger("chosen:updated");`](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#change-update-events)

```
var div_data = "";
$.each(json,function(i,obj) {
    div_data += "<option value="+obj[0]+">"+obj[1]+"</option>";
});

var $work_site = $('#work_site');
$(div_data).appendTo($work_site); 
$work_site.trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Comment: Stryner thanks for your replay but its not working still i have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing write one function in ajax success and in that success function bind the data to the dropdown and do `('#work_site').trigger("chosen:updated")`